# Can I configure always to take second `cn` value from multi-valued LDAP attribute?

Tags: ldap

LDAP can contain multi-valued attributes. For example, `cn` can be multi-valued attribute. See below LDAP RFC.

My application can process (show) only one `cn` value.
Will all entries in LDAP have same number of `cn` attributes?

Can I configure always to take second `cn` value?
What is a best practice to process multi-valued attributes in LDAP?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.3

```
   The 'cn' ('commonName' in X.500) attribute type contains names of an
   object.  Each name is one value of this multi-valued attribute.  If
   the object corresponds to a person, it is typically the person's full
   name.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will all entries in LDAP have same number of cn attributes?

No. Well, unless they are specifically added.

BTW: Some LDAP Server Implementations do NOT support multiple Values for cn. Microsoft Active Directory is one of them

> Can I configure always to take second cn value?

No. The return order of attributes is not defined within the RFC specifications and therefore is unknown. Some Specific LDAP Server implementations do return multi-valued attributes in a specific order. (Like FIFO or LIFO.

> What is a best practice to process multi-valued attributes in LDAP?

Can't say I have ever heard of a best practice. Guess it depends on the task you are trying to perform.

Comment: @Michael, excelent question. I'm facing this dilemma too. I need to implement a integration with LDAP servers and I would like to know what was your solution to handle when `cn` has more than one value.